# Unexpected behavior in inhomogeneous Cross K Function (Kcross.inhom)

Tags: r, spatial, bivariate, point-process

I am currently analyzing a point pattern in R using the "spatstat" package. I am comparing two different areas, therefore I made two plots for each area (first two plot-left-area1; second two plots-right-area2) [image]
I applied ginhom(r) for all the points from each area and the points have a random pattern, here is an example of the script:

```
#pcfinhom for area1 (first two plots)
bwp<- bw.pcf(poi_all, divisor="r", kernel="epanechnikov") #bw=1.426384 m
r1i<- envelope(poi_all, pcfinhom, nsim = 1000, savefuns=TRUE, conf.level= 0.95, correction= "isotropic", kernel = "epanechnikov", bw = bwp, renormalise=TRUE)
plot(r1i, xlab ="Distance r [m]", main= "pcf - Protected area", xlim = c(0,40), ylim=c(0,5), legend= F)
rlii<-LF.gof(r1i) # p value = 0.2117882 points are random
```

However, when I apply Kcross.inhom(r) to the assess the spatial relationship between different tree sizes from the area1 (first two plots), I receive strange graphs that I am not sure if are correct:

```
bw1 <- bw.diggle(poi_rr1, correction="isotropic", hmax=NULL, nr=400) #bw=9 m
pikros <- envelope(poi_rr1, Kcross.inhom, nsim=1000, i="A", j="S", correction = "isotropic",savefuns=TRUE, bw = bw1, renormalise=TRUE)
plot(pikros,main="Cross-K inhom - Protected area", xlab = "Distance r [m]",xlim = c(0,40), ylim=c(0, 500), legend = F)
pk <- LF.gof(pikros) # p value= 0.00990099 saplings are clustered around adults
```

I applied the same script for adults-intermediate (A, I) and intermediate-saplings (I,S) and the results can be seen in the following graphs:

## Graph: Kcross.inhom for adult - sapling trees: [image: Kcross.inhom for adult - sapling trees]

## Graph: Kcross.inhom for adult - intermediate trees: [image: Kcross.inhom for adult- intermediate trees]

## Graph Kcross.inhom for intermediate - sapling trees (without bw and a different kcross.inhom scale) [image: Kcross.inhom for intermediate - sapling trees]

For all the graphs, the p values are significant.
I tried bw.diggle = 9.6m, bw.stoyan = 1 m and bw.pcf= 3.3 m but I am not sure which is proper to use, since I received different values depending on the bw that I use.

## Question 1: Is there a specific bandwidth that should be used for Kcross.inhom(r)?

## Question 2: Is there a mistake in the script of the Kcross.inhom function or can I consider the graphs correct?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try to post on https://stackoverflow.com/ using the `spatstat` tag. Post your data if at all possible or generate an artificial dataset that behave similarly...

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I posted there and I added also some data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364272/pcfinhom-and-kcross-inhom-unexpected-behavior-heterogeneity-or-not